# Highcharts : is it possible to make specific plots of a series transparent.

Tags: highcharts

I am wondering if it is possible to make only specific points in a series transparent. 
I would really appreciate your time and help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be much more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
As per  your comment, you need to add connectNull in plotOption :

```
  plotOptions: {
          series: {
        connectNulls:true
                }
              }
```

and set all you points with 0(zero) values with "Null"

```
 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
 $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point){
     if(point.y == 0)
     {
         chart.series[0].data[i].update(null);
     }
 });
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/s4kjaagL/9/)

**Old**

If you want to set transparent color in specific bar ,pie-slice or column , you may set color and opacity as following

```
 color: 'rgba(x,y,z, 0.4)'
```

xyz are RGB and opacity see below code and [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/s4kjaagL/1/) ,it has dark blue column transparent.

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        color: 'rgba(0,0,255, 0.4)', //this
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]

    }
```

In area charts etc ,color gradient with stops can also be shown to show gradient .

Comment: Thank You! But thats not quite what i am looking for. Here is the same updated fiddle ->  http://jsfiddle.net/s4kjaagL/7/ 
In the dark blue series from ( feb to march) the series descends to '0'. I want that particular part to be transparent. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: means you don't want to connect points with 0 values. right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just want them to be transparent or not plot those points (with values '0') at all.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/s4kjaagL/8/ . is this is what you want? @Disera

Comment: Yes Thanks!. Is this the key -> connectNulls:true
And also, is it possible to avoid all points with '0' and plot the rest.

Comment: yes , you can do but for that see another change I did > I updated all the points with zero to null , pasting the code in answer

Comment: is it possible to make only the descending portion of a series as transparent instead of neglecting the zero values? i tried, but no luck.

Comment: descending portion  as transparent , mean you want to connect them and need lighter color ?